# Conditional passing of a default argument to a function (using the '?' operator)

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, default-arguments

There be a function declared as

```
CalculateTimeSilence(float SilenceThresholdOverride = -1.f);
```

Is there a way to call it, so that I can utilize the conditional '?' operator to either choose a value for *SilenceThresholdOverride* or **leave it at the default value**?

Expressed as pseudo-code:

```
CalculateTimeSilence(bUseOverride ? OverrideValue : default);
```

, where 'default' would be replaced by the compiler, by the value the argument was defaulted to in it's declaration (-1.f in this instance). 
If there were such a way, it would remove the need to match the default value or to write an If-Else statement.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: How about `bUseOverride ? CalculateTimeSilence(OverrideValue) : CalculateTimeSilence();` ?

Comment: @songyuanyao True. However, there may be scenarios in which this is not-so-pretty, if there are a lot of other parameters to the function. In any case, I was just curious whether anything like that existed, more than actually needing it. Thanks!

Comment: I think no. The default argument would be used only when passing no argument to the function, i.e. in the form of `CalculateTimeSilence()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling the function with out specifiying the parameter, then the default is added at the call site, so when you call

```
CalculateTimeSilence();
```

Then you are actually calling

```
CalculateTimeSilence(-1.f);
```

There is no `default` or similar mechanism to get the default argument, but you can do that "manually"

```
const float default_value = -1.f;

CalculateTimeSilence(float SilenceThresholdOverride = default_value);
```

and then you can call it as desired:

```
CalculateTimeSilence(bUseOverride ? OverrideValue : default_value);
```

However, while the conditional operator comes in handy sometimes, often it obfuscates code and makes it difficult to read. In this case I'd perhaps rather write

```
auto x = bUseOverride ? OverrideValue : default_value;
CalculateTimeSilence(x);
```